# Grails App unable to connect to SQL Server (Malformed Reply from SOCKS Server)

Tags: sql-server, grails

I'm a newbie learning Grails by developing a small application that retrieves codes from a database. The details are -
 - Apple Mac OS X (i.e. Unix).
 - Grails 1.3.5 using NetBeans 6.9.1.
 - SQL Server 2008 R2 Database, located on a different server.
 - JTDS Driver

Here is the DataSource.groovy -

```
dataSource {
    pooled = false
    driverClassName = "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver"
    dialect="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect"

}
hibernate {
    cache.use_second_level_cache = true
    cache.use_query_cache = true
    cache.provider_class = 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheProvider'
}
// environment specific settings
environments {
    development {
          dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update" // one of 'create', 'create-drop','update'
            url = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://hbtsqldev.domain.omitted.com.au:1433;databasename=TempDatabase;useCursorFetch=true;user=username;password=omitted"

        }
    }
    test {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"
            url = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://hbtsqldev.domain.omitted.com.au:1433;databasename=TempDatabase;useCursorFetch=true;user=username;password=omitted"
        }
    }
    production {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"
            url = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://hbtsqldev.domain.omitted.com.au:1433;databasename=TempDatabase;useCursorFetch=true;user=username;password=omitted"
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the Grails app, I receive the following (very long) error messages -

> 2010-11-11 10:58:00,709 [main] ERROR
>   context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error
>   executing bootstraps: Error creating
>   bean with name 'messageSource':
>   Initialization of bean failed; nested
>   exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name
>   'transactionManager': Cannot resolve
>   reference to bean 'sessionFactory'
>   while setting bean property
>   'sessionFactory'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name
>   'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve
>   reference to bean 'lobHandlerDetector'
>   while setting bean property
>   'lobHandler'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name
>   'lobHandlerDetector': Invocation of
>   init method failed; nested exception
>   is
>   org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException:
>   Error while extracting
>   DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is
>   java.sql.SQLException: Network error
>   IOException: Malformed reply from
>   SOCKS server
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name
>   'messageSource': Initialization of
>   bean failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name
>   'transactionManager': Cannot resolve
>   reference to bean 'sessionFactory'
>   while setting bean property
>   'sessionFactory'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name
>   'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve
>   reference to bean 'lobHandlerDetector'
>   while setting bean property
>   'lobHandler'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name
>   'lobHandlerDetector': Invocation of
>   init method failed; nested exception
>   is
>   org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException:
>   Error while extracting
>   DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is
>   java.sql.SQLException: Network error
>   IOException: Malformed reply from
>   SOCKS server  at
>   org.grails.tomcat.TomcatServer.start(TomcatServer.groovy:212)
>     at
>   grails.web.container.EmbeddableServer$start.call(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure5_closure12.doCall(_GrailsRun_groovy:158)
>     at
>   _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure5_closure12.doCall(_GrailsRun_groovy)
>     at
>   _GrailsSettings_groovy$_run_closure10.doCall(_GrailsSettings_groovy:280)
>     at
>   _GrailsSettings_groovy$_run_closure10.call(_GrailsSettings_groovy)
>     at
>   _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure5.doCall(_GrailsRun_groovy:149)
>     at
>   _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure5.call(_GrailsRun_groovy)
>     at
>   _GrailsRun_groovy.runInline(_GrailsRun_groovy:116)
>     at
>   _GrailsRun_groovy.this$4$runInline(_GrailsRun_groovy)
>     at
>   _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure1.doCall(_GrailsRun_groovy:59)  at
>   RunApp$_run_closure1.doCall(RunApp.groovy:33)     at
>   gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure5.doCall(Gant.groovy:381)
>     at
>   gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy:415)
>     at
>   gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy)  at
>   gant.Gant.withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy:427)
>     at
>   gant.Gant.this$2$withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy)
>     at
>   gant.Gant$this$2$withBuildListeners.callCurrent(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   gant.Gant.dispatch(Gant.groovy:415)
>     at
>   gant.Gant.this$2$dispatch(Gant.groovy)
>     at
>   gant.Gant.invokeMethod(Gant.groovy)
>     at
>   gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:590)
>     at
>   gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:589)
>   Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name
>   'transactionManager': Cannot resolve
>   reference to bean 'sessionFactory'
>   while setting bean property
>   'sessionFactory'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name
>   'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve
>   reference to bean 'lobHandlerDetector'
>   while setting bean property
>   'lobHandler'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name
>   'lobHandlerDetector': Invocation of
>   init method failed; nested exception
>   is
>   org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException:
>   Error while extracting
>   DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is
>   java.sql.SQLException: Network error
>   IOException: Malformed reply from
>   SOCKS server  ... 23 more Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name
>   'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve
>   reference to bean 'lobHandlerDetector'
>   while setting bean property
>   'lobHandler'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name
>   'lobHandlerDetector': Invocation of
>   init method failed; nested exception
>   is
>   org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException:
>   Error while extracting
>   DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is
>   java.sql.SQLException: Network error
>   IOException: Malformed reply from
>   SOCKS server  ... 23 more Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name
>   'lobHandlerDetector': Invocation of
>   init method failed; nested exception
>   is
>   org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException:
>   Error while extracting
>   DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is
>   java.sql.SQLException: Network error
>   IOException: Malformed reply from
>   SOCKS server  ... 23 more Caused by:
>   org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException:
>   Error while extracting
>   DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is
>   java.sql.SQLException: Network error
>   IOException: Malformed reply from
>   SOCKS server  ... 23 more Caused by:
>   java.sql.SQLException: Network error
>   IOException: Malformed reply from
>   SOCKS server  at
>   net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ConnectionJDBC2.(ConnectionJDBC2.java:410)
>     at
>   net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ConnectionJDBC3.(ConnectionJDBC3.java:50)
>     at
>   net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:184)
>     at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
>     at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:154)
>     at $Proxy8.getMetaData(Unknown
>   Source)   ... 23 more Caused by:
>   java.net.SocketException: Malformed
>   reply from SOCKS server   at
>   java.net.SocksSocketImpl.readSocksReply(SocksSocketImpl.java:147)
>     at
>   java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:495)
>     at
>   java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
>     at
>   net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SharedSocket.createSocketForJDBC3(SharedSocket.java:307)
>     at
>   net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SharedSocket.(SharedSocket.java:257)
>     at
>   net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ConnectionJDBC2.(ConnectionJDBC2.java:311)
>     ... 28 more

Can anyone see where the problem might be?
If you need me to provide any further info, please let me know.

Comment: Try removing `useCursorFetch` from the connection string. For a start, make sure that the connection user doesn't suffer from missing privileges. - Important: Look at the SQL Server logs.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to ping the database server from where you are running your tomcat? I am using Grails 1.3.5 with SQL Server 2005 with Microsoft JDBC 4.0 Driver. Works fine for me.

```
dataSource.driverClassName = com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
dataSource.url = jdbc:sqlserver://dbserver:1433;databaseName=testDB
```

Comment: I'm able to both ping and telnet the server, but I'm unable to establish a connection to the database in Grails or RazorSQL. In both cases I get a timeout connection error.